# Python PrettyTable read csv file Exception: Row has incorrect number of values, (actual) 0!=3 (expected)

Tags: python, csv, prettytable

I have python running on my MacBook Air. I have a simple example I'm trying to read in a csv using prettytable for python:

```
from prettytable import from_csv`
fp = open("test.csv", "r")`
pt = from_csv(fp)`
fp.close()
```

below is my csv "test.csv":

```
name,city,areacode
joe,chicago,312
sam,san diego,619
```

when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
%> python3 prettytable-testing2.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "prettytable-testing2.py", line 3, in <module>
pt = from_csv(fp)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/prettytable.py", line 1351, in from_csv
table.add_row([x.strip() for x in row])
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/prettytable.py", line 818, in add_row
raise Exception("Row has incorrect number of values, (actual) %d!=%d (expected)" %(len(row),len(self._field_names)))
Exception: Row has incorrect number of values, (actual) 0!=3 (expected)
```

Curious why it things it's getting 0 value when there are clearly 3 fields and 2 rows of items with pieces of data.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code but I didn't get the same error.

I think it may be possible that you have an empty line in the end of the file or somewhere. When I added an empty line, I got the error like you:

```
Exception: Row has incorrect number of values, (actual) 0!=3 (expected)
```

Comment: If you are not sure where the error is from, please try the code by only 1 line of csv file.